# Overriding PHP configuration options

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set some php configuration options using `.htaccess` file and then get them in php. 
If i write `php_value max_execution_time 21` then i can run `ini_get('max_execution_time')` in browser which returns 21 (using CLI it returns "0" but I dont know why).

However if I write `php_value error_log someValue` using `ini_get('error_log')` it returns boolean false in both browser and CLI. What is wrong with my configuration. How can I get values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLI is `PHP Command Line Interface`. As the name implies, this is a way of using PHP in the system command line. Or by other words it is a way of `running PHP Scripts that aren't on a web server` (such as Apache web server or Microsoft IIS)

`.htaccess` (hypertext access) is file is a directory-level configuration file that `works with web servers` such as Apache

The two of them are 2 different technology which mean PHP & .htacess can only share variables if you are running them on a `Web Server` not via `Command line`

Comment: Good point. I got it. It perfectly makes sense but why cant I set 'error_log' and then get it using ini_get() in browser. it only returns FALSE as if the configuration option doesn't exist.

Comment: my bad English again..sorry Ive ment that ini_get returns false which means option doesnt exist according to php.net. However Ive restarted apache it magically worked in browser. Thanks fo the great answer!